# Everyplay opens modal automatically after stopRecording is called

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, everyplay

I just installed your framework successfully to my cocos2d-v3 game project. My game has short runs and I want the player to be able to share he’s single runs.

So I call startRecording when my run starts.
    [[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] startRecording];
And stopRecording when it ends.
    [[[Everyplay sharedInstance] capture] stopRecording];

But when I call stopRecording it automatically opens the video modal and I don’t want that. I want to show a replay button and when player presses the button I will call playLastRecording-method. Am I doing something wrong or why stopRecording-method opens the modal automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have copied the everyplayRecordingStopped example implementation from the Everyplay integration guide without reading the code?

https://developers.everyplay.com/documentation/Everyplay-integration-to-Cocos2d-game.md